# Is it possible to send an automated SMS reply to incoming calls

Tags: sms, twilio, incoming-call

I'm wanting to send an automated SMS reply to incoming calls using Twilio. I have searched and have seen it work and the company that uses it is integrated with Twilio but I can't seem to find how to do it...? Any suggestions. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes it's possible. You can do this with Twilio Studio (https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio).

Comment: thanks, clarification, I see the autoresponder based on an incoming message get an error when I select to trigger based on an incoming call [
Send & Wait For Reply can't be attached to the Incoming Call trigger because incoming calls can come from unknown caller IDs. For more information, click on the trigger widget.]

Comment: Do you need "SEND & WAIT FOR REPLY"? Can you try with just a "SEND MESSAGE" widget?